# Minecraft pocket edition 0.10 iPad

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you find each player in a Minecraft world once you lost each other? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The compass will lead you to the origin. You both need to leave "breadcrumbs" or markers (torches or towers) as you follow the compass. The breadcrumbs are so that once you find each other, you can find your way back to where you were.
  My two daughters build houses in separate areas of the same world and couldn't find each other. I used the method above then built a rail line connecting them.